# How to ignore cell if it is blank?

Tags: excel

I have 3 worksheets in a single workbook: `Summary`, `Invoice`, and `Expense Report`. In the Summary sheet list of data, I have named cells as shown below:

`Customer_Name`: customer name

`Billing_Addr_1`: 1st line of billing address

`Billing_Addr_2`: 2nd line of billing address

`City_St_Zip`: City, State or Province, and Postal Code]

I'd like the info on the Summary Page to generate the Invoice. Everything works fine for `Customer_Name`, `Billing_Addr1` and `City_St_Zip`. I am having trouble handling customers who **do not** have a 2nd line of billing address.

If the customer doesn't have that second line (Suite 100 in this case) in the address, I want the invoice to simply skip it and show City_St_Zip.

For example:

*with 2nd address line*

```
John Doe Construction Co. 
123 Main Street 
Suite 100 
Anytown USA 12345
```

***without** 2nd address*

```
John Doe Construction Co. 
123 Main Street 
Anytown USA 12345
```

I have tried:

```
IF(ISBLANK(Billing_Addr2),City_St_Zip,Billing_Addr_2)
IF(ISBLANK(Summary!$D$15),City_St_Zip,Billing_Addr_2)
IF(ISBLANK(Summary!$D$15),City_St_Zip,Summary!$D$15)
IF(Summary!$D$15=0,City_St_Zip,Summary!$D$15)
```

I have looked in the help section in Excel itself and found it to be predictably obtuse and of zero help. I've done web searches about this problem and explored the results for quite some time and haven't found the answer. I realize that this is probably a very basic question and am embarrassed to be asking it, but can someone please point out my error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `=IF(Billing_Addr2="",City_St_Zip,Billing_Addr_2)`

Comment: A cell can't ever be "blank" if it contains a formula, even if that formula returns nothing visible, such as a null string, a space or a suppressed zero. Test for the length of the cell contents, e.g. `LEN(City_St-Zip)`. However this will return false of someone entered a space. Therefore the more reliable test is `LEN(TRIM(City_St_Zip))`, unless you intentionally want to leave a back door to force creation a blank line.

Comment: Maki, yes, I have tried that.  No luck.

Comment: can you post a sample of the data (screenshot of your worksheet) with and without the 2nd address line? also, how does that information get filled in? can you also send a screenshot of the formula bar with the addrs2 line in edit mode for a supposedly blank cell? Also are the named cells scoped to the workbook? Or do you have duplicate names scoped at multiple worksheet levels?

Comment: That's a bit pedantic @ScottHoltzman.  He did add _if it contains a formula_ :)  The comment given by @Maki looks close - could possibly do with a `TRIM` or some such to remove spaces but should be worth expanding and adding as an answer.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Fair point. My eyes glazed over that *if it contains a formula*. Comment deleted :)

Comment: @Scott Holtzman, I am not sure how to upload a screenshot.  (I'm struggling with this markup language.)  But I did confirm that when the Billing_Addr_2 cell is intended to be empty, the cursor is at the extreme left side of the formula bar.  The information is filled in by hand in the formula bar.  I have also confirmed the the cell names are scoped to the workbook level and that there are no duplicate cell names.

Comment: @TedPrice if you type `=ISBLANK(Billing_Addr_2)` into any random cell what happens when you enter / delete data in `Billing_Addr_2` cell.

Comment: @TedPrice:  Now, in that same cell, add to the formula by making it: `=IF(ISBLANK(Billing_Addr_2),TRUE,FALSE)`. If that produces correct results, then add: `=IF(ISBLANK(Billing_Addr_2),City_St_Zip,Billing_Addrs_2)` (FWIW I think you have had a typo the first time you tried this based on the typo of that formula in your original question. If it works in that cell then clear the entire contents formats etc of the cell where it won't work and try again.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, that cell shows the word "FALSE" (all upper, no quotes) when Billing_Addr_2 has text in it and "TRUE" (all upper, no quotes) when the cell is empty. Is something like this the answer to my problem?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, that did the trick.  Thank you!  I'm going to re-read my original question to find the typo.  Thank you again!

Comment: Well, I spoke too soon.  Now when I put "Suite 100" in Billing_Addr_2, an invalid name error is returned in the third line of the address block.

Comment: @TedPrice - check the spelling of your name ranges in the formula versus the actual named range. If you research what that error means you can also debug yourself :)